# Invite user to an organization rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-invitable

I have an enterprise app that keeps track of many `organization`s each of which can have many `user`s. What's the best way to construct a mailer that would allow a current Organization's User to invite other users to that Organization?

I'm currently looking into the `devise_invitable` gem, but not sure how to exactly execute what I want to do with it.

Comment: The `devise_invitable` gem is well documented, so please clarify your question: why do you think it would not fit, or what have you tried and where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 2):

I implemented invitations functionality in an enterprise application by making a few changes to this excellent example on rail casts. Kindly have a look. It works perfect for me and it is a very reliable and precise example. it uses email and invitation token to implement the functionality.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/124-beta-invitations

Comment: is there no way to do this with `devise_invitable`?

Comment: The procedure is very much closer to the example when using devise invitable gem. Have you tried using the gem, as instruction on the github page are very clear for how to use it. Which part are you having difficulty in understanding , I can help in implementing it

Comment: You will follow step to step instruction and when you are done with making the structure, you just have to add the invitation sending logic in the concerned controller.

Comment: https://github.com/javidjamae/devise-invitable-example , This is a working example code for devise invitable